# TypeScript, redux-form and connect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-form

First of all, I'm very new to TS, React & Redux, so sorry if this is an obvious question.

I'm trying to modify [this example](https://github.com/rangle/typescript-react-redux-example) to get a form to load some information. It's using [redux-form](http://redux-form.com).

I'm trying to figure out how to call `connect` and `redux-form` at the same time in the export of the component. Right now it's looking like this:

```
class UserForm extends React.Component<IUserProps, void> { .. }

export default ReduxForm.reduxForm({
  form: 'user',
  fields: [
    'userName',
    'password',
    'firstName',
    'lastName',
    'email'
  ],
  validate: UserForm.validate,
})(UserForm);
```

The examples I've seen [without TS](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1050) look like this:

```
class MyForm extends Component {}
MyForm = reduxForm(config)(MyForm)
MyForm = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyForm)
export default MyForm
```

But if I try to do the same in TS I get the TS2300 error: duplicate identifier.

I've also tried to use the `@connect` decorator, but I couldn't make it work (or find any working example online).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you just chain them?

```
class UserForm extends React.Component<IUserProps, void> { .. }

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps) 
    (ReduxForm.reduxForm({
  form: 'user',
  fields: [
    'userName',
    'password',
    'firstName',
    'lastName',
    'email'
  ],
  validate: UserForm.validate,
})(UserForm));
```

Answer (score 2):

not a fix, but issue can be silenced by casting to `any`

`connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyForm as any)`