# Is it necessary to wrap redux form field in a form tag?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm new to the redux form. I try to leverage the benefit it offers for one text input field in my react native app written in Typescript, literally just one text input field.

```
<Field name="payoutInput" type="text" component={this.renderPayout}/>

private renderPayout = (field: any) => (
    <View style={{flexDirection: "row", flex: 0.22, justifyContent: "flex-end"}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 17}}>
        $
      </Text>
      <TextInput style={{fontSize: 17}} defaultValue={String(this.props.balance)} autoFocus={true} keyboardType={'number-pad'} onEndEditing={this.calculatePayout}/>
    </View>
  )
```

What I notice is when I monitor the state in reactotron, I can't actually see the value in the form state. Using `formValueSelector` will also just give me `undefined`. So I'm wondering that if it's necessary to wrap the `Field` in a form?

Happy to provide more context on requested.

Comment: If that is the case, what should I use to wrap `Field` in typescript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46078452/438992, https://codesandbox.io/s/myoynq411j?module=%2FUserForm.tsx, https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/redux-form, https://github.com/snerks/redux-form-1, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; that's how it connects inputs to the redux form state.

This is noted in [the redux-form docs](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/gettingstarted.md/).

The redux-form docs [note on React Native](https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/faq/reactnative.md/) also says to follow [this tutorial](https://esbenp.github.io/2017/01/06/react-native-redux-form-immutable-styled-components/) to get started, and neither resource indicates it works differently under React Native.